# Opening a user profile page on one of the other sites creates a new browser window

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, flair

If I go to someone's user profile page and click on 'accounts' to see their associated accounts, and click on a profile link to another SOFU site, this opens a new browser page/tab. It would be much more polite if this was not done -- please let me decide if I wish to open a link in a new tab or not, thanks.

This is coming from the `target="_blank"` attribute in the anchor tag, in the https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/<userid>.html iframe.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, this annoys me as well. I'm perfectly capable of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking or middle-clicking if I want to follow the link in a new tab...

This sort of behavior makes some sense in the "Close as Duplicate" pop-up, where navigation would interfere with a half-completed action and the new window behavior thus serves as cheap protection against mis-clicks. But there's nothing to be *lost* on the associated profiles page, where the back button works just fine following navigation to an associated profile, bringing you back to where you left off...

Answer (score 4):

+1 from me, `target="_blank"` is super annoying.

Since it is in an iframe that is intended to be embedded on external sites, I guess `target="_parent"` or `target="_top"` would be correct.